# How to use the postgres-adapter in Socket.io in node.js

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-redis

My current setup is as such:
I have connected to my postgres database and i also have the websocket connected fine to the frontend.
But I am not sure how to use the postgres-adapter as its suggested in the documentation:
They say that you make a pool instead of a Client - thats fine for the db - then you say you use the `io.adapter(createAdapter(pool));`

The main functionality I want to get at is - when a change occurs on the postgresdb - then a notification gets send out just as I have currently - but then it should be connected inside the websocket for the websocket to send a message with the data to all connected clients. Has anyone implemented this?

```js
client.connect(err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error in connecting database: ", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Database connected");
    client.on('notification', (msg) => {
      console.log(msg.payload);
      console.log(msg)
    });
    const query = client.query("LISTEN update_notification");
  }
})

const webSocketSetup = (server) => {
  var io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: [
        'http://localhost:3000',
      ]
    }
  });
  
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('my message', (msg) => {
      "" I Want the postgres Notification to be setup here. ""
    });

  });
}
```